# Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments [] on settings 'MyApplication' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

Cuando ejecuto la app en un emulador, me genera el siguiente error >
**Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments [] on settings 'MyApplication' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings**

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Build.gradle luce asi

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debe a que tratas de llamar un mètodo el cual no existe.

Me parece que estas usando "Android Studio Arctic Fox" si no me equivoco, y este tiene algún problema con la versiòn de gradle que usas, dentro de tu archivo `gradle-wrapper.properties` cambia la url donde se define la distribuciòn gradle a la versiòn `7.0-rc-1`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-rc-1-bin.zip
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!